# Need help to understand this immediately invoked function example

Tags: javascript, javascript-objects, iife, module-pattern

This is a fragment of code I've found from a tutorial, but I can't understand clearly it's purpose. Here is the example:

app.js

```
var oojs = (function(oojs){



    return oojs;

}(oojs || {}));
```

The first part I'm confused is why it is called with the same parameter as it's argument?
The second doubt is why if there is no "oojs" should call the function with an object literal as parameter? Is this necessary? 
Finally why it should return the same as it's function name (oojs).

---

Maybe it's a way to create an object, but if someone could help me the need of this I will really appreciate.

Comment: Passing in the same variable name as you are using, while using `var` is essentially a failsafe. You are expecting `oojs` to exist and you want to use it, but if it isn't there, you are avoiding making a global variable out of `oojs`. For example, if you assumed `oojs` were available in scope and used `oojs = (function(){})()` and it had not been defined previously you would have made a global variable (assuming not in strict mode).

Comment: @Cœur You corrected the "*inmediately*" but could not fix "*invote*" to "*invoked*"?

Comment: @Cœur Oh, right, it's only obvious to those with a few [tag:js] badges…

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is just scoping rules in JavaScript. Whenever a new function is created, a new variable scope is created. The parameter name `oojs` is indeed the same *identifier* as the outside parameter `oojs` but it's more local.

Here is a simplified example

```
function foo(x){
    console.log(x + 2); 
}
var x = 3; // this is a different x, it belongs to the outer scope, and not the function
foo(x); // logs 5, since x is passed to the function, then x + 2 is logged
```

In this code example, the idea is to only change `oojs` if it doesn't exist, and then set it to the return value of the immediately invoked function expression. It's similar to a composing [module pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#modulepatternjavascript). Personally, I find the syntax rather confusing to read when a lot of lines are involved.